# Root with password fails but without password works

Tags: mysql, macos, root

I was working fine with my MySQL but after restarting my Mac I couldnt login to my root in which I had a password '1234'. I tried logging in with root without a password and it was successful but it doesn't have create privileges and doesn't contain my recent databases.

**------UPDATE------**

I stopped MySQL from the preferences in OS X. Then ran "ps aux | grep mysqld" and returned:

```
Jerald         18527   0.0  0.0  2432768    588 s002  R+    5:54PM   0:00.01 grep mysqld
```

I tried starting MySQL again from the GUI in preferences and ran "ps aux | grep mysqld" again and returned 3 processes now:

```
Jerald         18656   0.0  0.0  2432768    588 s002  R+    5:54PM   0:00.01 grep mysqld
_mysql         18641   0.0 21.4  3066380 449444   ??  S     5:54PM   0:00.86 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/Sarah.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/Sarah.local.pid
root           18543   0.0  0.0  2433436    992   ??  S     5:54PM   0:00.03 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/Sarah.local.pid
```

Which one should I kill now?

Comment: Sounds like you did your modifications in a different server. Maybe you accidentially started a separate instance in your session before?

Comment: I am working only on my local machine. At localhost. Any suggestions?

Comment: The term "server" does not, as often assumed, refer to a machine. That makes little sense. A server is a process, a server process. You run a mysql server on your system, and you can start _two_ mysql servers on the same system. That is what I was referring to.

Comment: That's weird. I installed MySQL using the dmg installer and I wouldn't have selected something that might be different from my current setup. If I did, how could I check it since the problem came up once I restarted my machine.

Comment: Easiest is to 1. check the process list, you should be able to see if the mysql processes belong together and 2. check for installed packages, especially for mysql executables. On linux systems you can simply ask the software management system for this, not sure what takes this place on a MAC.

Comment: I tried checking for processes and it seems that I do have multiple MySQL services if Im not mistaken. Which one should I kill in order to use the original one I installed and used? Please see my edit on my question.

Comment: No, the looks clean currently. The root owned process is the controller, the _mysql owned process is the actual server. So _currently_ there is only one server operating. So what happpens if you now make changes and restart the system afterwards? Changes lost again? It might also be interesting to manually shutdown the mysql server after you did some changes to see (in the log files) if it complains about something.

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed different mysql servers on your mac. For example I had installed one using MySql Installer and second came with MAMP. First of all you'd have to find out how many mysqld you have in your system. You can try following command.

```
find / -name mysqld
```

then you can find out which one is running using following command

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

then you can kill the running mysqld instance process using the following command and try the other one which might have your actual databases

`kill -9 XXXX`  (replace XXXX with process id which appears when you run the above command)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and the results are in my question as an update.